# Is multivariate Cauchy stable?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, linear, linear-algebra, multivariate-distribution, cauchy-distribution

I am trying to prove (if possible), for given $A_{n\times n}$ and $B_{n\times n}$, there exists a $C_{n\times n}$ satisfying $$A\pmb{X}_1 + B\pmb{X}_2 \stackrel{D}{=} C\pmb{X},$$ where $X_1, ~X_2$, and $X$ are independently and identically distributed Cauchy random variables with location vector $\pmb{0}$ and scale matrix  identity, $I$.

I planned to proceed using the characteristic function rather than using convolution:
\begin{align}
\Phi_{A\pmb{X}_1 + B\pmb{X}_2}(\pmb{t}) &= E\left(e^{i\pmb{t}^T(A\pmb{X}_1 + B\pmb{X}_2)}\right)\\
&=E\left(e^{i\pmb{t}^T(A\pmb{X}_1)}\right)E\left(e^{i\pmb{t}^T(B\pmb{X}_2)}\right)\\
&=E\left(e^{i(A^{T}\pmb{t})^T(\pmb{X}_1)}\right)E\left(e^{i(B^{T}\pmb{t})^T(\pmb{X}_2)}\right)\\
&=e^{-\sqrt{ \pmb{t}^TAA^{T}\pmb{t}}}e^{-\sqrt{ \pmb{t}^TBB^{T}\pmb{t}}},
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
\Phi_{C\pmb{X}}(\pmb{t}) &= e^{-\sqrt{ \pmb{t}^TCC^{T}\pmb{t}}};
\end{align}

thus comparing RHS and LHS will reduce the problem to finding a $C$, for given $A$ and $B$, satisfying $$ \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TAA^{T}\pmb{t}} + \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TBB^{T}\pmb{t}} = \sqrt{\pmb{t}^TCC^{T}\pmb{t}}, $$
for all possible choices of $\pmb{t}$.

After this step, the idea of taking different choices of $\pmb{t}$ to find an explicit solution of $C$ can be implemented, but I could not find $C$ explicitly in terms of $A$ and $B$ following this idea. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Note: $A$, $B$, and $C$ are real square matrices and $A^{T}$ indicates the transpose of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Such a $C$ does not exist in general unless $A$ and $B$ commute.  Use this fact to construct explicit counterexamples for $n=2.$

Comment: Can you find $C$ explicitly if $A$ and $B$ commute? If that is the case, you can assume so.

Comment: When $A$ and $B$ commute, upon simultaneous diagonalization the problem reduces to a set of one-dimensional problems.  I leave it to you to find the easy solution to those!

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable, then $A$ and $B$ commute. The converse is not necessarily true.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a counterexample.

Comment: Please visit this [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not a counterexample because your matrices $AA^\prime$ are special: they represent (positive-semidefinite) quadratic forms and are symmetric.

Comment: In your first comment, you said that the commutativity of $A$ and $B$ is needed. $A$ and $B$ are any real matrices. They are not necessarily symmetric or positive-semidefinite.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion that might have ensued by referrig to $A$ and $B$ when I meant $AA^\prime$ and $BB^\prime$.  The latter, of course, are what are involved in your question and so only the properties of the latter are going to be of any relevance to its solution.